# How can I stop updates running on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10

I have tried all the tricks in the book - setting connection as a metered connection (through registry), but there is no difference. I have already used up 1.1Gb in the last 24 hours as I try to fight this update process.

There is no option to set connection as a metered connection in the control panel.

If I search on start I set "Set up data usage limit" and from that window I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Other than the data use, why do you want to prevent updates?

Comment: Microsoft has been rightly criticized over the decades for a weak update system. They have gotten the message and made it very difficult to block updates entirely in Windows 10.

Comment: The best way to block update is to use WSUS instead.  This way you control which updates are pushed to your system.  You can only defer feature updates on Professional for 4 months (1507+) and cumlative quality (build.xxx) updates for 15 days (1703+ only)